# How to use Rules to set a value for a multi-value field?

Tags: commerce, rules

I'm trying to create an Order reference on Products when ever a new order is created. I have installed the "Order Reference" module and created an Order reference field on my product type.

Next I created the following rule:

- Rules Event: After saving a new commerce line item
- Rules Conditions:

  1. Data comparison ( [commerce-line-item:type], Data value: Product )
  2. Data comparison ( [commerce-line-item..., Data value: NAME OF TYPE )
- Rules Action: Set data value [commerce-line-item..., Value: [commerce-line-item:order]

The above rule works fine as long as i limit the Order Reference field to 1 value, but as soon as it is set to multiple the rule breaks.. i get the following error for the action:

> Error: The data type of the configured argument does not match the
>   parameter's value requirement.

I'm new to the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module and a kind a lost here. Any help?

Below is the exported rule:

```
{
  "rules_test_test_order_ref": {
    "LABEL": "test test order ref",
    "PLUGIN": "reaction rule",
    "OWNER": "rules",
    "REQUIRES": [
      "rules",
      "entity"
    ],
    "ON": {
      "commerce_line_item_insert": []
    },
    "IF": [
      {
        "data_is": {
          "data": [
            "commerce-line-item:type"
          ],
          "value": "product"
        }
      },
      {
        "data_is": {
          "data": [
            "commerce-line-item:commerce-product:type"
          ],
          "value": "iq_test_event"
        }
      }
    ],
    "DO": [
      {
        "data_set": {
          "data": [
            "commerce-line-item:commerce-product:field-order-reference"
          ],
          "value": [
            "commerce-line-item:order"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you could just use the "Add to list" Rules Action. And since your question is about a multi-value field, for sure you should NOT use a  Rules Action like "Set a data value", which is used to set assign a single value to a field (which seems to be what you've tried, a common mistake when using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module for such fields).

Refer to the answer to "[How to set multiple values to an unlimited Term Refence field with Rules](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/220892/how-to-set-multiple-values-to-an-unlimited-term-refence-field-with-rules/220894#220894)" for "some" more details ...

PS: I'm assuming this question is about D7.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone should be looking for the same functionality i found a solution, creating my own action, in this post :)

[Update values of multiple value field programmatically? (Rules action)](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/106707/update-values-of-multiple-value-field-programmatically-rules-action)